# Batch script (cmd) resulting in DD-MM-YYYY_weekday format

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, conversion, date

I need to use date /t command and convert the date format to DD-MM-YYYY_weekday with all the "-" and "_" as listed
I can't find an answer on my question. Could you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `weekday`?

Comment: for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%1 in ('date /t') do set date=%%2%%3%%1
tried this one

Comment: weekday - for example, monday

Comment: @Anastasiya Done. See my answer that uses the local independent (correct) way of retrieving the required information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I would like to have it formatted like DD-MM-YYYY_weekday

Below are two solutions:

- Batch file
- PowerShell (a simple one line solution)

---

#### The Batch file solution

First, what not to do:

- Using `%date%` to provide a solution is, as used in the other answers, dependent on the OS Locale, Regional, and Language settings and may provide wrong or missing information.
- For example, the short date format on my PC does not output the weekday at all.

The right way to solve the problem:

- Using `wmic`, on the other hand, works independently of OS Locale, Language or the user's chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).

The following batch file uses `wmic` to retrieve the date and (local) time, so doesn't suffer the disadvantage of a solution using `%date%`.

The batch file also calls PowerShell to retrieve the weekday, as that is not directly available otherwise.

**getdate.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the date
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%g in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _day=00%%g
  set _month=00%%h
  set _year=%%i
  )
rem pad day and month with leading zeros
set _month=%_month:~-2%
set _day=%_day:~-2%
rem get day of the week
for /f %%k in ('powershell ^(get-date^).DayOfWeek') do (
  set _dow=%%k
  )
rem output format required is DD-MM-YYYY_weekday
echo %_day%-%_month%-%_year%_%_dow%
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>getdate
06-06-2016_Monday
```

Credits:

- Thanks to [Danny Beckett](https://serverfault.com/users/151904/danny-beckett) for [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/690816/251339) which provided the PowerShell weekday trick.

---

#### Alternative Powershell solution.

A simple one line PowerShell solution is:

```
Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd_dddd"
```

Example output:

```
PS F:\test> Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd_dddd"
2016-06-06_Monday
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) - Display the date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or the users chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Now I only need to understand it :)

Comment: @Anastasiya You are welcome. I had most of the code already available, but it took a little while to figure out how the get the weekday.

Comment: It would take too long to explain ;)

Comment: This have the side-effect of changing the font of my console window. It seems that it is specifically a side-effect of calling power shell.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Doesn't change my font ...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`echo %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%date:~0,3%`

[Source](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for manipulation tips

Comment: Output is `01-6/-_06/`.

Comment: @DavidPostill If you have an alternative solution, feel free to post it. Repeating the comment isn't adding much value.

Comment: @uSlackr I will be.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It uses the `for` command to tear apart the `date /t` results and uses `echo` to construct the output. The details can be worked out at the command-line.

`for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %a in ('date /t') do echo %b-%c-%d_%a`